# How would I test this method with JEST?

Tags: testing, methods, jestjs, box, white-framework

This is my first time trying JEST and I was wondering how I would write a test for my Length.convert() where I am accounting for "I" or different, but not specifically for "I" and "M". How would I test that specifically?

MY LENGTH CLASS

```
class Length {
  constructor(measure, system) {
    this.measure = measure;
    this.system = system;
  }

  convert() {
    if (this.system === "I") {
      return (this.measure * 2.54).toFixed(2);
    } else {
      return (this.measure * 0.393701).toFixed(2);
    }
  }
}

const firstLength = new Length(20, "I");
const secondLength = new Length(7, "M");

console.log(firstLength);
console.log(firstLength.convert());
console.log(secondLength);
console.log(secondLength.convert());
```

MY JEST TEST

```
const constructor = require("./length");
const convert = require("./length");

test("", () => {
  expect().toBe();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed the ecmascript version base on the `require("")`.

The working solution can be found here: [Stack-blitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-vd5za8?file=length.test.js)
To prove it is working: just type ***nmp test*** in the stack-blitz console

Length class needs to be exported like this

*Length.js*

```js
class Length {
  // The other code is omitted
}

module.exports = Length;
```

Only the constructor has to be imported.
And in order to use it, you need to create an instance within the test

*Length.test.js*

```js
const Length = require('./length.js');

test('Test Description', () => {
  //SETUP
  const length = new Length(1, 'I');

  //ACT
  const result = length.convert();

  //ASSERT
  expect(result).toBe('2.54');
});
```